# How to avoid re-execute the query on a MoveFirst

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, recordset

I have a query in a ASP page. The record set that I obtein must be printed in 3 different tables, after some conditions. So, for avoid extecuting 3 times almost the same query, I decided to search the recordset for the results I need...so I need to make a RS.MoveFirst two times.
But...when I analyzed with SQL Profiler, I saw that MoveFirst operation re-executes my query...exactly what I wanted to avoid.
How can I do the cache the results and only move around the recordset?

Comment: Snapshot or Dynamic data set?  Is dbSeeChanges used?

Comment: forwardonly (the default)
Obs: I don't need to get the changes after the first execution of the query

Answer (score 3):

Use a disconnected recordset

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adUseClient = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Dim conn: Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open sYourConnectionString

Dim rs : Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

rs.Open sYourSQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
conn.close

'' // You can now roam around the recordset with .MoveFirst, .MoveNext etc without 
'' // incurring any further hits on the DB.
```

Note that if you have parameters to supply to your sql you will need to use an `ADODB.Command` object between the connection and recordset (don't be tempted to use string concatenation).  Still the principle is the same use a client cursor location and static recordset then detach and close the connection.

Comment: ```adOpenStatic = 3```

Uses a static cursor. **A static copy of a set of records** that you can use to find data or generate reports. Additions, changes, or deletions by other users are not visible.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee252445(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: What if you are using a command object to return the recordset?

Answer (score 2):

personally i would simply use `rs.getRows()` and navigate into the array... not only are u sure u never hit the database again you should see a huge gain of performance everytime you use it